# hosting multiple websites on apache under one ip address

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I am trying to host multiple websites (app.diff1.com and app.diff2.com running on tomcat server) on my apache server which are running on ports 8082 and 8083 respectively, to access them i want to use a single domain name (app.in.xxx.com/**diff**) along with a differentiater (diff1/diff2).I used url rewriting to change the domain names respectively. Now when i am trying to access the websites i always end up with hitting the first virtual host.
Please suggest me if i am not approaching the solution correctly.

Code snippet:

in httpd.conf file.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app\.in\.xxx\.com/([a-z]*)$
      RewriteRule ^ http://www.app.%1.com [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyRequests off         
    </IfModule>

    NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.app.diff1.com
      ProxyPass / http://www.app.diff1.com:8082/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://www.app.diff1.com:8082/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.app.diff2.com
      ProxyPass / http://www.app.diff2.com:8083/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://www.app.diff2.com:8083/ 
   </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your rewrites into the first listed virtual host, and stop trying to capture the first path component of the URL as if it were part of HTTP_HOST -- capture it in the RewriteRule itself and use $1.

Also see ServerPath which is an esoteric way to do the same mapping.